# How to make HTTP protocol in Facebook Canvas

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I want to framed my website on facebook canvas.
My page has HTTP protocol and facebook not open it:

"This URL must use the HTTPS protocols."

In application settings is two input:

[image]

without secure canvas, application not load and with this get error message:

"This Connection is Untrusted"

I want to insert my HTTP site on facebook.
Is this impossible?
Only HTTPS is allow?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, you need a server with SSL certificate. Some people recommend this for a cheap solution: http://www.startssl.com/

Comment: Is there any way to insert my page of the facebook application? What is other apps: iOS, 
 
Android, 
  
Facebook Canvas, 
 
Website

Comment: iOS/Android: just a normal native mobile app. facebook canvas: iframe with https on apps.facebook.com/yournamespace. website is for external websites - if you want to use facebook login, for example.

Comment: you only need ssl for canvas and page apps.